# Inserting underscore in place of single or multiple spaces(consecutive) in a string

Tags: javascript

Eg.

```
1."abc";   ===>abc
2."ab c";  ===>ab_c
3."ab  c"; ===>ab_c
4."ab   c" ===>ab_c
```

similarly for multiple consecutive spaces.
How can i achieve that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** with regex **[`\s+`](https://regex101.com/r/hN7rR7/1)**

```js
function removeSpace(str) {
  return str.replace(/\s+/g, '_');
}

console.log(removeSpace('abc'));
console.log(removeSpace('ab c'));
console.log(removeSpace('ab  c'));
console.log(removeSpace('ab    c'));
```